# Import MySQL DB Schema

Tags: mysql, database, import, database-schema

I have successfully used mysqldump to export a db schema without data. I now want to import this db schema.

I have tried a couple of methods but come across the error related to the < character.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, input redirection in PowerShell does not work with the `<`sign. You would do it using the Cmdlet `Get-Content` and use piping to put the output into the input of the command:

`Get-Content v:\mcsdb.sql | mysql -u root --sql --recreate-schema mcs`

If you are interested in more in-depth info, refer to the [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx).